# Wordpress get_posts() post limit

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress's function the_excerpt(). It works fine, but in the result is only shows 5 of my post's. How can I make it display all posts instead of only the 5 most recent?

My code:

```
<?php

    $lastposts = get_posts();

    foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :

            setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <p style="font-size:12;"><em>Post date: <?php the_date(); ?></em></p>

            <?php the_excerpt() ?>

            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read more...</a>

            wp_reset_postdata();

    php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: try `$lastposts = get_posts(array('nopaging' =>true));`

Comment: It sounds like your problem isn't with the_excerpt() but rather with get_posts(), since that is the loop you're iterating over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not with `the_excerpt()` but rather with `get_posts()`, since that is the array your loop is iterating over.

Try:

```
<?php

$lastposts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => -1));

foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
...
```